# HTTP Error 500 when deploying ASP.NET Core 2.2 to additional Azure Web App

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have already deployed the application to a Azure web app that works just fine. I am using an **ASP.NET Core 2.2** application with **MVC** connected to a **SQL server** located on Azure. I am working with **dotnet SDK version 3.1.301**.

The application has a **React client**. I am trying to make the application multi - tenancy, therefore, each web app has its own **Azure Key Vault** but a **single database**. All of the environment variables are located within the key vault, including the connection string to the db.

I have created an additional web app on Azure (this one is for production) connected to an additional Key Vault. After deploying to this web app, I get a HTTP 500 error. In the web activity logs I do not receive any errors. I am using **Microsoft Visual 2019** to deploy the applications.

My question is; I have followed all the same steps for the first deployment and I would really like to know why, when spinning up a new app with a new key vault, why I am not getting any errors?

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                var keyVaultUri = builtConfig.GetValue<string>("KEY_VAULT_URI"); //Connection to KEY VAULT
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUri, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        }
        ).UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ILearnerService, LearnerService>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            // Fixed Unexpected end of JSON
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
            option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddCors();
        // Configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<ILearnerService, LearnerService>();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory **********
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });

        // Configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration;

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        services.AddMultiTenancy()
            .WithResolutionStrategy<HostResolutionStrategy>()
            .WithStore<InMemoryTenantStore>();

        // Configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        var encryptionKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings.EncryptionSecret);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(TenantFeatures.Inbox, policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .RequireAssertion(context =>
                        context.User.HasClaim(TenantFeatures.Inbox, "user.Stores.Companies"))
                    .Build();
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var learnerService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILearnerService>();
                    var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                    var user = learnerService.GetById(userId);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                        context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                    }
                    // user.Stores.Companies
                    var tenantInfo = Configuration.GetValue<string>("tesco-training-net");
                    if (tenantInfo.Contains(TenantFeatures.Inbox))
                    {
                        Claim claim = new Claim(TenantFeatures.Inbox, "user.Stores.Companies");
                        ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(claim);
                    }
                    if (tenantInfo.Contains(TenantFeatures.DynamicCV))
                    {
                        Claim claim = new Claim(TenantFeatures.DynamicCV, "user.Stores.Companies");
                        ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(claim);
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

            };
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                // Fixed [Authorize] decrypts the tokens
                TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encryptionKey),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x
           .AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMultiTenancy();
        app.UseMvc();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Within the Application logs, I am getting this:

IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or 
application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.

IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.

The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.

The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Comment: you are saying "ASP.NET Core 2.2" but also "working with dotnet SDK version 3.1.301.". Can you please clarify which version you are using? I can be only either 2.2 or 3.1 - otherwise maybe right there is your issue?!

Comment: In the .csproj file it states that the target framework is netcoreapp2.2. when running dotnet --info in the command prompt it says I am using .NET Core SDK version 3.1301. I have just inherited this project and am very much in the dark. not entirely certain if I am supposed to downgrade the SDK or upgrade my NuGet packages?

Comment: well you cannot successfully build and run a project that targets 2.2 with 3.1. So you either need to downgrade your SDK or upgrade your project (which is probably a bit more effort than just upgrading your nuget packages, based on your app's complexity)

Comment: I would suggest checking the app settings to make sure the values are correct.

Comment: Is sounds like your immediate problem is a lack of logging/debugging.